# Running CMD opens a duplicate form

Tags: c#

you are probably confused about the title and me too, this is baffling me. whenever i run the code below to open cmd, run ipconfig and paste it into the textbox, all it does is make a duplicate form appear. Why? i have absolutly no idea. i replaced the code with "textbox1.text = "hi"; which worked fine so it must be this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    textBox1.Text = output;
}
```

is it just me doing something stupid, im very tired so it might be

Here is a gif of the duplicate form appearing [image]

Comment: What's a "duplicate form"? Maybe a screenshot...

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Paste *what* into *what textbox*? None of your code makes a *form* appear, so how can it be making a *duplicate*? You're absolutely right; your title is confusing, and your question text does nothing to clear that confusion.

Comment: thats whats  baffling me, can i include a gyazo screenshot here?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1abc270130d5c6f83afaf7aab2807f2f - i dont know how to make it into a link but thats what its giving me

Comment: You can add a link to a graphic by making an [edit] to your post, putting the cursor where you want the graphic to appear, and then clicking the graphic button on the toolbar or pressing Ctrl+G and following the instructions on the screen.

Comment: ok thats alot better, i know some people might be abit sceptical about links. i still have no idea why its doing this tho

Comment: Comment out the lines related to redirecting and reading standard output. Does that stop the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program named ipconfig.exe and code simply launches its own executable again.

Specify absolute path to fix.

Comment: ooohhhhhhhhhhhh of course, that makes alot more sense. i thought i was going crazy, thanks alexei